Existence of non-intersecting semicircular arcs connecting every points in a given set
This is a problem that I came up with a few months ago.

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ points on a plane ($n \ge 3$), and let $e(c)$ denote the set of the two end points of the semicircle $c$. A semicircular cycle on $S$ is a set of semicircles $C$ such that for every semicircles $c \in C$, $e(c) \subset S$ and the undirected simple graph $G=(S, E)$ is isomorphic to the cycle graph $C_{n}$, where $E=\{e(c) \mid c \in C\}$. We say that a set of semicircles $C$ is consistent if every pair of distinct semicircles in $C$ have at most $1$ point of intersection, and they only intersect with each other if they share one common end point (so the only point of intersection is their common end point).

Here's an example of a consistent semicircular cycle on a random set of points.

If $S$ is the set of vertices of a convex polygon $P$, then there is a fairly straightforward way to construct a consistent semicircular cycle, by drawing semicircles between the end points of each edge of $P$ "pointing" outwards like this:

But more generally, is it true that for any finite set of points $S$, there always exist a consistent semicircular cycle on $S$? My guess is that this is true since I wasn't able to find or construct any counterexamples so far, however I couldn't prove or disprove it.
Some thoughts on the problem
If we want to decide if there exists a consistent semicircular cycle on point set $S$ with a given ordering of points $(p_1, p_2,...p_n)$, this problem can be seen as a 2-SAT problem. Since each pair of points decides exactly two semicircles, we can assign one of them to be "positive" and the other one "negative" (This assignment is arbitary). Let $c_{i, j}$ denote a semicircle whose end points are $\{p_i, p_j\} $. We can define a one-to-one mapping $f$ that maps a semicircle to a boolean literal: $$f(c_{i, j})=
\begin{cases}
x_{i, j} & \text{if $c_{i, j}$ is positive}\\
\neg x_{i, j} & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$. We can construct the following 2-CNF formula:$$\bigwedge_{\substack{c, d \in C^{'} \\ e(c) \neq e(d) \\ \text{{c, d} is not consistent}}}(\neg f(c) \lor \neg f(d)),$$
where $C^{'}$ is the set of all semicircles whose end points are $\{p_i, p_{i+1}\}, i \in \{1, 2, ..., n-1\}$ or $\{p_n, p_1\}$. If there is a valid assignment of variables that makes this boolean formula true, then the set of semicircles $C=\{c|c \in C^{'}, f(c)=\text{TRUE}\}$ is a consistent semicircular cycle on $S$. This is useful for creating an algorithm to find consistent semicircular cycles in a given set of points (if one exists), but I am not sure if this is helpful for proving or disproving the original problem.

What a cool problem! What have you tried? Sometimes the best way to grope towards a proof of a general statement is to look for a counterexample (seek out the "worst" possible configurations) and to figure out why this search always fails. Please edit your post to include your thoughts so far.

@SammyBlack Thank you for your reply. I've edited my question to include some of my thoughts on the problem.

I do not see any points of intersections (just points of ends of semicircles - the drawing helps in understanding what you mean). It is clear that in many cases there are more than one solution (even many solutions). Just note that there are 2n! possible sequences of which one needs to meet your requirement. Is this a good AI challenge?:)

Could you use Proof by Induction to demonstrate this?

Another phrasing: given a set of points in the plane, draw all circles with diameters between pairs of points, and interpret this as a plane multi-graph. Is there always a non-crossing Hamiltonian cycle?
